# The derivative of a Heaviside-composite function

Tags: derivatives, dirac-delta

The derivative of the Heaviside function is the delta function, however, I found this problem difficult to understand why we get the following:

$f(t)=\theta(t)\sin(3t)$

$f'(t)=\theta(t)'\sin(3t)+\sin(3t)'\theta(t)=\delta(t)\sin(3t)+3\cos(3t)\theta(t)$

But then,

$f''(t)=\delta(t)'\sin(3t)+3\cos(3t)'\theta(t)=\delta(t)\sin(3t)-9\theta(t)\sin(3t)$

But the [correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=second%20derivative%20of%20sin%283x%29%5Ctheta%28x%29) answer is in fact $f''(t)=3\delta(t)-9\theta(t)\sin(3t)$

What happened to the product rule here?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I made a mistake in my calculations, and I use it to show what I thought

$f''(t)=(\delta(t)\sin(3t))'+3(\cos(3t)\theta(t))'=\delta(t)'\sin(3t)+3\delta(t)\cos(3t)-9(\sin(3t)\theta(t))+3(\cos(3t)\delta(t))$

Assuming $\delta(t)f(t)=0$, we get $3\delta(t)\cos(3t)=0$:

$f''(t)=\delta(t)'\sin(3t)-9(\sin(3t)\theta(t))$

But then, this [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=delta%28t%29%27sin%283t%29) shows that $\delta(t)'\sin(3t)=0$, so

$f''(t)=-9(\sin(3t)\theta(t))$

but this is still wrong.

Is there a method to identify the correct way to differentiate this, without all these complex integrals?

Comment: how did you obtained $6\delta(t)\cos(3t)$?

Comment: Do you mean $6\delta(t)cos(3t)$? It is by the product rule on $(\delta(t)sin(3t))$, treating $delta(t)$ as f and $\sin(3t)$ as f. Then adding it to the product rule product $3(\cos(3t)\theta(t)$, where $\theta$ is differentiated to $\delta$, thus have two times $3(\cos(3t)\delta(t)$

Comment: But what did you do to the $\delta'(t)$ term?

Comment: I used your notion "Assuming $\delta(t)′f(t)=0$, we get:"

Comment: Sure, but you still have this term $\delta'(t)\sin(3t)$ in the calculations you wrote. Note that $\delta'(t)$ is not the same as $\theta'(t)=\delta(t)$. I mean, $\delta'(t)\sin(3t)$ is not necessarily 0

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. The new update shows that I don't know what to make out of $\delta(t)'sin(3t)$

Comment: Oh ok. So, you use the property $\delta'(t)g(t) =- \delta(t)g'(t)$. Did you got my answer bellow? I answered with the detailed process there on how to deal with $\delta(t)'\sin(3t)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134037/discussion-between-luthier-and-feedbacklooper).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how rigorous is this answer but this might clarify the WA result.

First, you have this property $\delta(t)g(t)=\delta(t)g(0)$. So
$$
f'(t) = \theta'(t)\sin(3t) + 3\cos(3t)\theta(t) = 3\cos(3t)\theta(t)
$$
since $\theta'(t)\sin(3t)=\delta(t)\sin(3t)=\delta(t)\sin(0) = \delta(t)(0)=0$.

Now,
$$
f''(t) = 3\theta'(t)-9\sin(3t) = 3\delta(t)-9\sin(3t)
$$
as the result from WA.

Now, I believe this is consistent with what you obtained using the product rule (not chain rule), except from the last part of your result. The mistake you made is to assume that $\delta'(t)=\delta(t)$ which is not.

Assume we didn't simplify $\theta'(t)\sin(3t)=0$. Hence,
$$
f'(t) = \delta(t)\sin(3t) + 3\cos(3t)\theta(t)
$$
so that
$$
f''(t) = \delta(t)'\sin(3t) + 3\delta(t)\cos(3t) + 3\delta(t)-9\sin(3t)
$$
Now, use $3\delta(t)\cos(3t) = 3\delta(t)\cos(0) = 3\delta(t)$. But also, we know that the main property of $\delta'(t)$ is that $\delta'(t)g(t) =- \delta(t)g'(t)$. Hence,
$$
\delta(t)'\sin(3t) = -3\delta(t)\cos(3t) =-3\delta(t)\cos(0) = -3\delta(t)
$$
Thus,
$$
f''(t) = -3\delta(t)+3\delta(t)+3\delta(t)-9\sin(3t) = 3\delta(t)-9\sin(3t)
$$
similarly as obtained before.

Summary: use dirac delta properties $\delta(t)g(t)=\delta(t)g(0)$ and $\delta'(t)g(t) =- \delta(t)g'(t)$. The first one is a consequence of the delta being 0 everywhere except at $t=0$ and the second one is a consequence of integration by parts.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "Assume we didn't simplify $\theta′(t)sin(3t)=0$, " I have seen this in another source. Can we say that this accounts for any function, when we have $\theta(t)'f(t)$?

Comment: I don't exactly know for which functions it doesn't hold, but $\sin(3t)$ being of one the nicest functions out there, I'm sure it holds. You can also check this by making the integrals to see that $\theta'(t)\sin(3t)$ is the same distribution as $0$ when acting on test functions.

Comment: Graphically,  $\delta(t)\sin(3t)$ is a sharp infinite peak at $x=0$ multiplied by the sine function. How does that give $0$?---, though I believe you.

Comment: Because the "graphical reasoning" doesn't work with $\delta(t)$ since it is not really a function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform calculations on $f(t) = \theta(t) \sin(3t)$ in the sense of distributions. Take a smooth test function $\psi$ then we have that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int f^{'}\psi dt &= \int (\theta(t) \ \sin(3t))^{'} \ \psi (t) \ dt \\
&= \int \theta ^{'}(t) \ \sin(3t) \ \psi (t) \ dt + \int \theta (t) \  \sin^{'}(3t) \ \psi (t) \ dt \\
&= \int \delta(t) \ \sin(3t) \ \psi (t) \ dt + \int \theta (t) \  \sin^{'}(3t)\ \psi (t) \ dt \\
&= \underbrace{\sin(0) \ \psi(0)}_0 + \int \theta (t) \ 3 \cos(3t) \ \psi (t) \ dt \\
\end{aligned} 
$$

Thus:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int f^{''}\psi dt &= + \int \delta (t) \ 3 \cos(3t) \ \psi (t) \ dt + \int \theta(t) \ 3 \cos^{'}(3t) \ \psi (t) \ dt \\
&= + 3 \cos(0) \psi(0) - \int \theta(t) \ 9 \sin(3t) \ \psi (t) \ dt \\
&= + 3 \int \delta(t)\ \psi(t) \ dt - \int \theta(t) \ 9 \sin(3t) \ \psi (t) \ dt \\
\end{aligned} 
$$

Thus: $f^{''} (t) = 3 \delta(t) - 9 \theta(t) \sin(3t)$ in the sense of distributions. Notice that integration here is an abuse of notation.

Comment: What do you mean by "Notice that integration here is an abuse of notation"? What would be the correct notation?

Comment: I mean that the integration here is not a Riemannian or Lebesgue integration. With distributions one talks about actions of these distributions on some test functions, and we cannot always represent these actions by integrals. See also my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3911688/636628